# How to get a particular value from input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

My user can add his any audio from reverbnation.com. So user can copy his embed code and paste it my form input. I want my form get only two word from input text.

**For example:-** reverbnation embad code like as:

```
<iframe class="widget_iframe" src="https://www.reverbnation.com/widget_code/html_widget/artist_4859830?widget_id=50&amp;posted_by=label_265034&pwc[design]=customized&pwc[background_color]=%23d4c79f&pwc[included_songs]=0&pwc[song_ids]=23591473&pwc[photo]=0%2C1&pwc[size]=undefined" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

So if my user paste above embed code in form input field,
I want to collect two word from above text to save it my sql database.

1. Artist Id = `4859830` (...artist_4859830?...)
2. Song Id = `23591473` (...&pwc[song_ids]=23591473...)

Please give me a guideline; How to collect above 2 id from input field.

My sql database: id | userid | artist | song

my form page:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['code']);
    $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['userid']);

    $artist = How to get artist id (4859830) from $code 
    $song = How to get song id (23591473) from $code

    $result = mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO user_aideo (id, userid, artist, song) values('', '$userid', '$artist', '$song')");
}

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<? echo $session->userid; ?>"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value=" Submit "/>
</form>
```

Comment: The input string is always in the same format/ pattern??

Comment: I believe someone will use magical regex to solve this question, but I'll ask some info for them, 1. artist pattern is always `artist_xxxxxxx?(or artist_xxxxxxx&)` ? 2. is that `pwc` before `[song]` always appear?

Comment: @Jamel No, It will be variable always. Thank you.

Comment: Just use parse_url and parse_str, no need for "magical regex"

Comment: If its always in the same format then (1) perform some regex on both of them or (2) take input char by char and split it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that this would be a good use case for [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

For your particular scenario, you can capture both numbers in one execution. You just need to use the `preg_match` function.

```
if (preg_match("/(?:.*)artist_([0-9]*)\?(?:.*)song_ids]=([0-9]*)/i", $code, $matches)) {
    print 'artist: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
    print 'song: ' . $matches[2];
}
```

This works with your given code example. It will put the artist number in `$matches[1]` and the song number in `$matches[2]`.

I'm comfortable directly referencing these in an if statement because the regular expression has two capturing groups, so there will always be 3 indexes in the `$matches` array if `preg_match` returns `true`. If you make a direct call to `preg_match` outside of an if statement, you will want to loop through the `$matches` array to avoid an undefined index error.